# iOS 13 Disclosure Indicator icon dim color

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

Recently I am working with UITableview and I noticed that the table view cell accessory  'Disclosure Indicator' icon is dim in iOS 13. I checked in the iOS 12 device, where it is ok. Is there any way to solve this issue without using a custom image.

This is what I got in [iOS 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQYZf.png)

And this is in [iOS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPbPN.png)

Answer (score 2):

There’s no way to change the appearance of the disclosure indicator. You can use the system images that are included with iOS 13 if you don't want to use a custom image.

Just set the `tintColor` of your `TableView` to the color you want & set the `accessoryView` of the `TableViewCell`.

```
cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right"))
```